# Падает сервис на Linux

Tags: linux

Необходимо создать и запустить сервис под Linux, программа написана на go, скомпилина в бинарник с именем `check_connect_asiiu`, далее:

```
mkdir check-connect-asiiu/;
sudo mv check_connect_asiiu check-connect-asiiu/;
sudo chmod 775 check-connect-asiiu/check_connect_asiiu;
sudo touch /lib/systemd/system/check_connect_asiiu.service;
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/check_connect_asiiu.service
```

Файл check_connect_modules.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Check DB
After=default.target
After=mysql.service
Requires=mysql.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/zahp/check-connect-asiiu/
ExecStart=/home/zahp/check-connect-asiiu/check_connect_asiiu
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=always
User=root
Group=root
StandardOutput=null
PIDFile=/run/check_connect_asiiu.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
Alias=check_connect_asiiu.service
```

после выполняю:

```
sudo systemctl enable check_connect_asiiu.service;
sudo systemctl start check_connect_asiiu.service;
sudo systemctl daemon-reload;
sudo systemctl status -l check_connect_asiiu.service
```

На что мне выдается:

```
● check_connect_asiiu.service - Check DB
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/check_connect_asiiu.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Вт 2018-09-18 17:33:23 MSK; 6min ago
  Process: 28597 ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28591 ExecStart=/home/zahp/check-connect-asiiu/check_connect_asiiu (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28591 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

сен 18 17:33:23 zahp-pc systemd[1]: check_connect_asiiu.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
сен 18 17:33:23 zahp-pc systemd[1]: Stopping Check DB...
сен 18 17:33:23 zahp-pc systemd[1]: Starting Check DB...
сен 18 17:33:23 zahp-pc systemd[1]: check_connect_asiiu.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
сен 18 17:33:23 zahp-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start Check DB.
сен 18 17:33:23 zahp-pc systemd[1]: Unit check_connect_asiiu.service entered failed state.
```

По созданным программой файлам можно понять что она начинает работать но падает (программа запускает 4 горутины), если же запускать непосредственно бинарник, то программа работает отлично

В чем может быть причина падения?

Comment: вполне допускаю, что программа хочет писать в домашний каталог, а ей этого делать нельзя.

Comment: Читайте логи в `sudo journalctl -u check_connect_asiiu.service`, и да, daemon-reload нужно делать перед стартом, а не после (хотя наверно это неважно в данном случае)

Comment: В логах:
`Starting Check DB...
Started Check DB.
check_connect_asiiu.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
...
check_connect_asiiu.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Failed to start Check DB.
Unit check_connect_asiiu.service entered failed state.`

Comment: Это явно неполные логи, они намекают, что перед ними было что-то ещё

Comment: сен 18 17:24:31 zahp-pc systemd[1]: Starting Check DB...
сен 18 17:24:31 zahp-pc systemd[1]: Started Check DB.
сен 18 17:24:31 zahp-pc systemd[1]: check_connect_asiiu.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
сен 18 17:24:31 zahp-pc systemd[1]: Stopping Check DB...


Повторяются эти строки

Comment: @Geo Вы запускали вашу программу на прямую без systemd?  если да приведите пример лога работающей программы. Если она падает и в этом случае - проблема не в systemd.

Comment: тут последовательность не верная `sudo systemctl enable check_connect_asiiu.service;
sudo systemctl start check_connect_asiiu.service;
sudo systemctl daemon-reload;`   daemon-reload 1й все остальное после

Comment: И у вас ничего не падает, программа завршилась с выходом 0 `Process: 28591 ExecStart=/home/zahp/check-connect-asiiu/check_connect_asiiu (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28591 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
` и перезгарзилась `Restart=always`.  - __If set to always, the service will be restarted regardless of whether it exited cleanly or not, got terminated abnormally by a signal, or hit a timeout.__

Comment: @Hellseher при обычном запуске не отключается

Comment: @Hellseher поправил код, пришлось от многопоточности отойти, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо @Hellseher Проблема не с настройкой сервиса, а с программой